# How to make Unity independent of every workspace?

Tags: 12.04, unity

I've been trying to get used to working with the workspaces, but the fact that the programs I use in workspace1 is accessible from every other workspace using unity, annoys me.

For example, when some folder is opened in workspace1 and I'm trying to open the home folder in workspace2 by clicking "Home Folder" , it takes me to the opened folder in workspace1.

How can I make Unity independent of every workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspaces are a feature of the Unity desktop, hence there is not way to "separate" then from Unity(at least as far as I know).

For some applications (Pidgin and Libre Office, according to my quick tests) there can only be on instance running so clicking to the icon will take you back to the workspace where it is active.

For others, particularly for your mentioned concern --the home folder(Nautilus), if you right click the icon it will give you the option to **Open a New Window**, selecting this will open a new window in the current workspace and leave the windows in the other workspaces as they were(open to whatever location you left them at).

NOTE, however that if you right click the icon on **any** workspace and click "Quit" it will close **all** open windows on all workspaces.

I'm not sure all or the  other programs can be opened on multiple workspaces simultaneously, but Firefox(and I assume most other browsers) can.  (I would assume that any programs that shows the option to open a new window can be opened this way but I don't know that for sure.)

I know this didn't directly answer your question on **how** because I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but I hope it was useful in a "no but you can do this instead" kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

If you middle click on a starter item Unity will try to start a new instance of that application instead of switching to an already open window.

For applications that can't have more than one instance running at a time this may not work. In some cases it will move the open window to your current workspace.